# Problem related to spring/resources.xml while deploying Grails applicatoin war in tomcat

Tags: spring, grails, resources, tomcat6, war

I have developed an application (named CBR) in Grails 1.3.7. When i run it with "grails run-app" or "grails run-app prod" it works fine. However when i create a war using "grails war" command and then deploy this war in Tomcat 6.0.32 i see following exception:

```
            Sep 22, 2011 1:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
            INFO: Deploying web application archive CBR.war
            context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
            org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in
             XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/resources.xml] is in
            valid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

                    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
                    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
                    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
            Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1059)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
                    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
                    ... 3 more
            Sep 22, 2011 1:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
            SEVERE: Error listenerStart
            Sep 22, 2011 1:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
            SEVERE: Context [/CBR] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Although the project was fully unpacked. I have checked conf/spring/resources.xml ... its empty.

I have ready all the threads similar to war deployment problem in Tomcat, but was unable to sort it out.

Following is the code from my config.groovy file:

```
environments {
  production {
    grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
  }
  development {
    grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}/auth"
  }
  test {
    grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
  }
}
```

And, from Datasource.groovy file:

```
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbr?autoreconnect=true"
    }
  }
  test {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbr?autoreconnect=true"
    }
  }
  production {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbr_prod?autoreconnect=true"
    }
  }
}
```

And some more detail from application.properties file:

```
app.grails.version=1.3.7
app.name=CBR
app.servlet.version=2.4
app.version=0.1
plugins.autotranslate=0.3
plugins.hibernate=1.3.7
plugins.message-reports=0.1
plugins.navigation=1.2
plugins.richui=0.8
plugins.shiro=1.1.3
plugins.tomcat=1.3.7
plugins.xfire=0.8.3
```

I have spent last 2 days to sort out the issue. Please help me, it took me 1 month to develop this application.

Comment: It's always useful to try `grails prod run-war` to see if it's a general WAR problem or something specific to your Tomcat configuration. That said, do you have an empty 'resources.xml' file in your 'grails-app/conf/spring' directory? If so, just remove it.

Comment: What is the content of `/WEB-INF/spring/resources.xml` inside the war?

Comment: This looks like a dependency crash for me. Check the dependencies of the plugins you are using and search for some outdated stuff. I guess you should try to remove all plugins from the application.properties execpt for hibernate and tomcat, and try to get your application running on tomcat. I am sure you will find it this way. Good luck

Comment: thanks for the suggestions
@Peter I have also tried to run `grails pro run-war` but it always ended in an error though `grails war` always worked.

Comment: @jeha its empty.
@crudolf i have already tried to get it worked by removing all the plugins, but it didn't.
I will try to delete the `resources.xml` as @Peter recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be much of an answer, but something you should definitely try before you tie yourself in a knot...

The first things I mistrust when I run into issues where something should obviously work, are the state of my build and the state of my machine's configuration.

Since you haven't gone through the complete build-deploy cycle yet, you might make sure that it would work at all with your configuration.

Build a simple Hello World grails app, generate the war file and deploy it. If that works, I'd start adding plugins and config changes to see if any of these break anything. Shouldn't take you more than 20 minutes.

Good Luck